# Get value from usePermission('microphone')

Tags: vuejs3, vueuse

I would like to check user permission in vue 3 ecosystem.

`const mic = usePermission('microphone')`

However in response i get *RefImpl* When i log in in console  `console.log(mic)`i see value 'granted'. But when i get `console.log(mic.value)` i get undefined. So how can i get actual value if user grant or not mic in this case ? In doc i see changes that *RefImpl* was done for ssr.
I just want to know when user is on page is he actually allow mic usage.

Answer (score 1):

It's retrieving the permission asynchronously.

FYI console.log with objects can sometimes be deceiving. With console.log, [object property values are lazily retrieved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#logging_objects), which means you're not seeing the true value at the time of logging.

Try this instead

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(mic)))
```

This shows the actual value at the time you console.log it.  You'll see no `value` property, hence why you get `undefined` when logging just that property.

The permission returned by `usePermission` will update reactively, and you can see the value be updated if logged in a watcher:

```js
watchEffect(() => {
  console.log(mic.value)
})
```

Just don't try using `mic.value` before this update occurs (e.g. not in created or mounted hook) and you should be fine.